# Why can't use mac audio feature when install Kubuntu in VirtualBox on macOS?

Tags: macos, virtualbox, audio, kde, kubuntu

Versions I'm using

- macOS: 10.15.4
- VirtualBox: 6.1
- Kubuntu: 20.04

I installed Kubuntu and everything works well but I found I can't use audio feature when it's running. If I shutdown it, the audio feature went normal.

But I also tried to install Ubuntu 20.04 in VirtualBox on macOS, it doesn't has any issue both about itself and macOS.

What will be the reason?

Comment: Please don't cross-post to multiple SE sites. Pick one & stick to it. https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/391635/why-cant-use-mac-audio-feature-when-install-kubuntu-in-virtualbox-on-macos

Comment: Sorry, I can't understand your post. The sound doesn't work on Kubuntu VM? Is it?